# Waffle JAAS Authentication

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, authentication, kerberos

I am trying to integrate [waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle) in my web app project (jsp). I want to authenticate user for my webapp, from Active directory(following Kerberos protocol ).

Whenever user hint the url firstly tomcat server authenticate the user from Active directory server, upon authentication user can use my web application (jsp).

Here's the setting I followed for implementing waffle. When I hit the url pop up occur for verification after successful login it shows

**HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied**

context.xml

```
    <Context>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" 
    appName="Jaas" 
    userClassNames="waffle.jaas.UserPrincipal"
    roleClassNames="waffle.jaas.RolePrincipal" 
    useContextClassLoader="false" 
    debug="true" />
</Context>
```

web.xml

```
      <login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Jaas</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
  <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
</security-role>


<security-constraint>
  <display-name>Waffle Security Constraint</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

login.conf

```
    Jaas {
    waffle.jaas.WindowsLoginModule sufficient;
};
```

jaas.policy

```
    grant Principal * * {
  permission java.security.AllPermission "/*";
};
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below configuration, it works for me.

```
<security-role>
  <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
  <display-name>Waffle Security Constraint</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```